# Derive time steps to display in x-axis in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am implementing a rest service using spring boot to generate a JSON response for a mobile client to plot it on a spline chart.

One of the expected property in the response is **timeSteps**, which is the data to be displayed on the x-axis of the graph. The tables where the data is pulled from has a timestamp field, FYI.

However, I am not sure how to derive the time steps. Could anyone share a hint or an example as to how I can generate it?

Comment: Hello! Stack overflow isn't really the sort of place where you'll get given examples of code. It's more about solving specific problems. Have you got any attempts at the code that aren't working that we might be able to help with?

Comment: Hello Christopher, I will keep that in mind going forward. In this case, I am not sure how to derive it. Sorry I don't have a code snippet to share at the moment because I don't know "how" to derive it. So once you have the resultset that has to be mapped to model, you can work on it to "divide" it somehow. Honestly, I have not done this before and couldn't find a hint on internet which made me post the question in SO.